# Настройка маршрутов в netplan ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, yaml, netplan

Столкнулся с проблемой изменить метрику у маршрута в ubuntu 22
Вот так выглядит маршрут в `route -n`

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы при загрузке метрика была 40.
Для этого в файле /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml прописываю следующее условие:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    wlp0s20f3:
      dhcp4: true
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.1
          metric: 40
```

выполняю команды

```
sudo netplan generate 
sudo netplan apply
```

После этих действий в таблице маршрутизации маршрут не меняется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно произвести настройку?

Comment: мама дорогая. уже двадцать три года, как начался двадцать первый век, а всё ещё можно встретить упоминания [окаменевших остатков](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712) под названием `route`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию, буду использовать `ip route` )
Просто я видимо сильно привык к виду таблицы как выводит `route`.